# increment by +2 pandas to excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a list of dataframes.  Is there a way for each loop to increase the increment by +2 each time?  So my dataframe in excel looks like:

```
while True:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\xzx.xlsx")
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    df3.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, startcol=+2, index = False)
```

dataframe:

```
                   A         B  
2000-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 
2000-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  
2000-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 
2000-01-04  0.721555 -0.706771 
2000-01-05 -0.424972  0.567020 
2000-01-06 -0.673690  0.113648 
2000-01-07  0.404705  0.577046 
2000-01-08 -0.370647 -1.157892
```

Ideal:

```
               A         B    C     D         E
        0.469112 -0.282863        0.469112 -0.282863
        1.212112 -0.173215        1.212112 -0.173215
       -0.861849 -2.104569        0.861849 -2.104569
        0.721555 -0.706771        0.721555 -0.706771
       -0.424972  0.567020       -0.424972  0.567020
       -0.673690  0.113648       -0.673690  0.113648
        0.404705  0.577046        0.404705  0.577046
       -0.370647 -1.157892       -0.370647 -1.157892
```

+2 also gives the same output in each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pd.concat`too:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': {'2000-01-01': 0.469112,
  '2000-01-02': 1.212112,
  '2000-01-03': -0.861849,
  '2000-01-04': 0.7215550000000001,
  '2000-01-05': -0.424972,
  '2000-01-06': -0.67369,
  '2000-01-07': 0.40470500000000004,
  '2000-01-08': -0.370647},
 'B': {'2000-01-01': -0.28286300000000003,
  '2000-01-02': -0.173215,
  '2000-01-03': -2.1045689999999997,
  '2000-01-04': -0.706771,
  '2000-01-05': 0.56702,
  '2000-01-06': 0.113648,
  '2000-01-07': 0.5770460000000001,
  '2000-01-08': -1.157892}}

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a series to append "empty" column in loop
extra_col = pd.Series(index=df.index,data=[""]*len(df))

# Create loop
while True:
    df = pd.concat((df,extra_col,df),axis=1)
    # Let's break if more than 10 columns
    if len(df.T) > 10:
        break

# Optional rename columns
alphabet = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
df.columns = (alphabet[i] for i in list(range(len(df.columns))))

# Output
df.to_excel("test.xlsx",header=False,index=False)
```

Comment: Does this work in a loop and increment?  E.g for While true?

Comment: Infinite amount.

Comment: I want to basically in a loop increment each time +2 as new set of data each time.  The reason for infinite loops is just generally simpler.  I will use an if statement to get out of loop

Comment: @gerrybro Ok got, it.. look at the solution now

Comment: Not an infinite loop.  It does 3 loops.

Comment: @gerrybro Yes because I break.. if not my pc crashes.

Comment: That makes sense.  I removed     if len(df.T) > 10:
        break.  Nearly crashed my pc too, though no new data was iterated through.

Comment: Silly me.  excel was out of loop

Comment: @gerrybro Hahhaha I'm still confused... hope this helped you.

Comment: Your previous solution worked.   df.to_excel("test.xlsx",header=False,index=False) was not indented.  I ran it.  Assumed it did not work.  Left it on in background.  And my sound got disabled and my computer almost crashed LOL.

Comment: @gerrybro You are always free to edit my post. Good luck!

Comment: Actually my solution only generated the new bit at the specified column offset. Concatenating is way better (I was already looking at `openpyxl` solutions to bypass this flaw..). Deleted mine.